# Image sharing in social media apps installed in the iphone/ipad/

Tags: ios

Is there any built-in api/Code in iOS that allow the app to detect what other social media apps installed in the iphone/ipad/ipod touch to populate out the sharing features?

Comment: Check this: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22289-possible-retrieve-these-information.html

Comment: thankq :) bt im nt getting the exact thing. will u help me in this ?

Comment: **Apple apparently does not have any function that checks this for you, so I whipped one up. It does not enumerate every single app, instead it uses the MobileInstallation cache**...
In that link , clearly mentioned code and with explanation . Why can't you give a try ...?